# EEXIST Error on npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant

I'm running NPM install with Vagrant shell and I get this error.  I've tried removing the `/home/vagrant/.npm` directory and `npm cache clear` yet I still get the error.  Thanks!

```
npm ERR! EEXIST, open '/home/vagrant/.npm/8fdf262d-rant-npm-json5-0-4-0-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: /home/vagrant/.npm/8fdf262d-rant-npm-json5-0-4-0-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again. 

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-62-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /working-directory
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/.npm/8fdf262d-rant-npm-json5-0-4-0-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of version of npm do you use?

- Open the command line / Shell and run `npm version`
- Update npm / nodejs to the latest version by downloading it from the website
- Open a new command window and make sure you have the latest version(`npm version`)
- Run `npm install`.

This solved it to me.